# How do I block a Gmail avatar from showing up on emails?

Tags: gmail, avatar

Anybody know how to block a person's Gmail avatar picture from showing up when that person sends you a message? (For example, I need to communicate with an ex-spouse but really have no need or desire to continually view her picture.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a desktop mail client like Thunderbird. If that's unacceptable, see if AdBlock [can help you](https://adblockplus.org/en/elemhidehelper)

Answer (score 2):

You could edit this person's contact info on your Gmail contacts and set the picture you want (a grey square if you wish).

Comment: I tested this and it works. You can choose "No photo".